# How can I dynamically generate TableLayouts and add them to an existing LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-tablelayout

I have the following `LinearLayout`, into which I want to insert a number of dynamically generated `TableLayout`s. This runs without any errors but nothing is appearing on the screen. Why aren't the `TableLayout`s appearing? How can I generate the `TableLayout`s and add them to the `LinearLayout`?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblOverviewText">  
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I'm generating the `TableLayout`s:

```
var linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout2);
foreach (var block in status.blocks)
{

    var tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent);
    var rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FillParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

    var tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.LayoutParameters = tableParams;


    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.LayoutParameters =tableParams;

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.Text = block.Name;
    textView.LayoutParameters = rowParams;

    tableRow.AddView(textView);

    tableLayout.AddView(tableRow, rowParams);
    linearLayout.AddView(tableLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start I would delete the alignParentLeft/alignParentRight in the xml for the linearlayout and simply put android:layout_width="match_parent".
You will also need to define the 'orientation' property of the linearlayout in the xml as 'vertical'.

The next part of the problem is the complicated mix of different kinds of layout params, you have correctly identified the need for table and row layout params seperatley but have defined the rowParams variable as a 'new TableLayout.LayoutParams' instead of which it should be 'new TableRow.LayoutParams' but both should have a width of match_parent and a height of wrap_content.  Code example below:

```
  LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    for(int i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++)
    {
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(0, true);//NOTE: you may not want this if you do not want your textview to always fill the available space

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(listItems[i]);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tableRow.addView(textView);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    }
```

Hope this helps.